# Permission denied when trying to access mounted windows NFS

Tags: linux, networking, windows, nfs, storage

I am trying to mount an NFS folder that I have set up on a WIN08 server. The NFS is mounting successfully, but I am unable to access it.

This is my fstab

```
x.x.x.x:/Music /home/osmc/Music nfs rw,nolock,x-systemd.automount,noauto 0 0
```

and my folders/error

[image: and my folders/error]

This is my setup on the Windows Server. 1000 is the UID/GID of the osmc user on my server, and it looks like it's pulling correctly.

[image]

I have a feeling I need to change something on the Windows side, but I'm not sure where else to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: You have the Windows system set up to export the flle system read-only, and you're mounting it with "rw" permissions.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thought about that, but I still get denied if I change to read/write and reboot/remount. http://i.icap.me/1143601390874b2.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking "Allow unmapped user Unix access". This may change things if the Windows side doesn't know about the osmc account.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh509017%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Wow. After hours of trying to fix this, that small little thing made it work, lol. Thanks!