# NFS mount permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, windows, nfs

I have a windows 2012R2 and NFS server, and Ubuntu 18 on the client side configured by following [this link](https://blog.bobbyallen.me/2018/01/18/windows-server-2016-as-an-nfs-server-for-linux-clients/)

They are in the same network. As root , I am able to mount properly the NFS in Linux. But as a regular user I get a ‘permission denied ‘ message. Even if I try to write a file to the previously mounted NFS directory , I get a ‘permission denied ‘ message too.

If I create a file as root in the NFS mount, I can't read it from Windows also because lack of permissions (Normal behavior I think).

In Windows I have set the permission Open for all computers to NFS. And my regular user in Ubuntu has no root access. What configuration am I missing?

The solution proposed in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213837/permission-denied-when-trying-to-access-mounted-windows-nfs) doesn't work since I have checked everything in the NFS share options.

Comment: How is the Ubuntu machine authenticating? The "permission denied" is most likely happening because the UIDs and GIDs don't match on the client and server.

Comment: I have local users on both sides, in fact the username/password is the same. How can I configure it to send the credentials from Linux to Windows?

Comment: NFS does not authenticate via the username or the password. It authenticates via the UID and GID. Are they they same on both the client and server? Do the users and/or a group that the clients are have permissions to the directories and files on the server?

Comment: You will have to change the UIDs and GIDs on the client to match the ones on the server or else have the client authenticate via AD and give Unix attributes to the user accounts in AD. The first method is much easier.

Comment: @NasirRiley Even if I have checked the box of enabling access of non mapping users? In that case which one is the good UID and GID? You're right, even I have no AD configured in my scenario.

Comment: Yes, even then. If the UID doesn't match, then the clients aren't going to be able to see anything.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I was sharing my hard drive folder. When i did mount the hard drive folder locally first and the shared the mounted folder, it worked. I have answered it in more details [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088354/mount-nfs-mount2-permission-denied/1312880#1312880)